# Changing the ColdFusion 9 standard license key

Tags: coldfusion, licensing, coldfusion-9

I understand ColdFusion 9 is no longer supported, but we are still using it for some systems until we can migrate to ColdFusion 10.

We were using a hosting provider who was providing us the ColdFusion 9 standard license and charging us for it. We found an unused license key (for ColdFusion 9 standard) and want to use that instead of getting charged a leasing fee from the hosting provider.

I understand the steps are to log-in to ColdFusion Admin, click on the System Information icon and enter the new license key.

Anything else we need to be aware of so that there are no unexpected issues?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is all you need to do. As long as the license key is valid CF9 will update to that license and stay running in standard mode.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I did not know if we had to restart ColdFusion services or not.

Comment: Nlope you don't need to restart.